# how to get the number of pixel, the div has dragged in jquery ui interaction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am developing a designer app which drag an div inside another div in jquery. It allows and resizing and dragging div which is placed in outer div.
I am using jquery ui interaction libraries.

I have place part of My original code block is as below

```
     $("#canvas-holder").droppable({    
     accept: '.cmp',
     tolerance: 'pointer',
     drop: function(event, ui) {
             $('#save_button').prop("disabled", false);
             x = ui.helper.clone();
             $(this).append(x.attr('id',generateUniqueID(x)).addClass("resizable ui-resizable"));
             $("#canvas-holder .cmp").addClass("item");
             $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable cmp");


             current_component_height = $("#canvas-holder").height();
             current_component_width = $("#canvas-holder").width();
             existingElements[$(x).attr("id")] = [current_component_height,current_component_width] 
             alert(JSON.stringify(existingElements))

             $(".item").css({
                 "left": $("#canvas-holder").offset().left+"px",
                 "top": $("#canvas-holder").offset().top+"px",
                 "height": ($("#canvas-holder").height())/4+"px",
                 "width": $("#canvas-holder").width()+"px"
             });


             $(".item").resizable({resize: function(event, ui) {
                                    $("form input[name=width]").removeAttr('max')
                                    $("form input[name=height]").removeAttr('max')
                                     restrictSize(ui);
                                     console.log("before: "+$(this).height())
                                     var height = $(this).height() * 5.0;
                                    console.log("after: "+height)
                                     if($(this).height() <= canvasHeight){
                                       $("form input[name=height]").val(height)
                                     }else{
                                       var rem=(canvasHeight - $(this).height())*5
                                       height= Math.round(height + rem); 
                                       $("form input[name=height]").val(height)
                                     }

                                     var width = $(this).width() * 5.0;
                                     if($(this).width() <= canvasWidth){
                                         $("form input[name=width]").val(width)
                                     }else{
                                       var rem=(canvasWidth - $(this).width())*5
                                       width= Math.round(width + rem); 
                                       $("form input[name=width]").val(width)
                                     }
                                     }
                         });

             $(".item").draggable({
                 containment: '#canvas-holder',
                 drag: function(){
                     console.log($(this).scrollTop())
                     $("form input[name=width]").removeAttr('max')
                     $("form input[name=height]").removeAttr('max')
                     var offset = $(this).offset();
                     if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
                        var comp_ypoint = offset.top - canvas_ypoint;
                        var comp_xpoint = offset.left - canvas_xpoint;
                        comp_xpoint = comp_xpoint * 5.0
                        comp_ypoint = comp_ypoint * 5.0

                        if(comp_xpoint>=0)
                             $("form #x-cord-id").val(comp_xpoint)

                        if(comp_ypoint>=0)
                            $("form #y-cord-id").val(comp_ypoint)
                     }
             }
             });
```

I am implementing new feature but for that I want to know if there is any method which can give me the number of pixels the div has moved vertically and horizontally.
I tried to found about this for almost 8 hours.
Could someone tell me if there is a build in function or else how can i make one?

Comment: draggable has start and stop events. Use those to get what you need. Inspect the `ui` object in each and it should be fairly simple to calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second parameter that's passed into the `drag` event handler:

```
drag: function(e,ui) {
    var verticalDistance = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top;
    var horizontalDistance = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left;
    // ... etc
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nwk255ar/

reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you so much... :))